# Read and extract from file

Tags: c#

I have a huge file with ~3 mill rows. Every line contains record like this:

```
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9
```

Exactly 8 separators like '|' on every line. I am looking for a way to read this file then extract last '9' number only from every line and store it into another file.

edit:

Ok here is what i done already.

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filepath))
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filepath1))
    {
        string line = null;
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            sw.WriteLine(line.Split('|')[8]);
    }

File.WriteAllLines("filepath", File.ReadAllLines(filepath).Where(l => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(l)));
```

Read file, extract last digits then write in new file and clear blank lines. Last digit is 10-15 symbols and I want to extract first 6. I continue to read and try some and when I'm done or have some question I'll edit again.

Thanks

Edit 2:
Ok, here I take first 8 digits from the number:

```
 sw.WriteLine(line.Substring(0, Math.Min(line.Length, 8)));
```

Edit 3:
I have no idea how can I match now every numbers that left in file. I want to match them and to see witch number how many times is in the file.

Any help?

Comment: Lovely. Have fun. If you have any problems be sure to let us know.

Comment: I just started and looking for some ideas or tutorial as I'm not advanced in c# so much. Thank you

Comment: Best of luck! Just go one step at a time: break it into little tasks and when you're happy the first bit works move onto the next. Enjoy :)

Comment: Tutorials you won't fine, but ideas i can give: [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx), [split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx), [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx).

Comment: in case someone ask if every line is the same or something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("input"))
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("output"))
    {
        string line = null;
        while ((line=sr.ReadLine())!=null)
            sw.WriteLine(line.Split('|')[8]);
    }
```

Comment: this will write one line :)

Comment: Heh, typed it out without thinking. :) I've corrected it now.

Answer (score 3):

> I am looking for a way to read this file then extract last [..] number only from every line and store it into another file.

What part exactly are you having trouble with? In psuedo code, this is what you want:

```
fileReader = OpenFile("input")
fileWriter = OpenFile("output")

while !fileReader.EndOfFile 
    line = fileReader.ReadLine
    records[] = line.Split('|')
    value = records[8]
    fileWriter.WriteLine(value)
do
```

So start implementing it and feel free to ask a question on any specific line you're having trouble with. Each line of code I posted contains enough pointers to figure out the C# code or the terms to do a web search for it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't say where you are stuck. Break the problem down:

```
 Write and run minimal C# program

 Read lines from file

 Break up one line

 write result line to a file
```

Are you stuck on any one of those? Then ask a specific question about that. This decomposition technique is key to many programming tasks, and indeed complex tasks in general.

You might find the [string split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) capability useful.

Answer (score 2):

Because it's a huge file you must read it line by line!

```
public IEnumerable ReadFileIterator(String filePath)
        {
            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(filePath, Encoding.Default))
            {
                String line;
                while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    yield return line;
                }
                yield break;
            }
        }

        public void WriteToFile(String inputFilePath, String outputFilePath)
        {
            using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(outputFilePath, true, Encoding.Default))
            {
                foreach (String line in ReadFileIterator(inputFilePath))
                {
                    String[] subStrings = line.Split('|');
                    streamWriter.WriteLine(subStrings[8]);
                }
                streamWriter.Flush();
                streamWriter.Close();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `String.Split()` to get the line inside an array and get the last element and store it into another file. Repeat the process for each line.

Answer (score 1):

Some pointer to start from: [`StreamReader.Readline()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx) and [`String.Split()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx). There are examples on both pages.

Answer (score 1):

With LINQ you could do a thing like the following to filter the numbers:

```
var numbers = from l in File.ReadLines(fileName)
              let p = l.Split('|')
              select p[8];
```

and then write them into a new file like that:

```
File.WriteAllText(newFileName, String.Join("\r\n", numbers));
```

Comment: It is not a problem, File.ReadLines() returns an IEnumerable in a lazy way.

Comment: Wonder what will happen when you call `String.Join` with ~3 mill records

Comment: Why not `File.WriteAllLines()` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
// Read the file and display it line by line.
System.IO.StreamReader file = 
   new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\test.txt");
while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
     string[] words = s.Split('|');
    string value = words [8]
   Console.WriteLine (value);

}

file.Close();
```